# MOS Capacitor Band Edges

Tags: mosfet, analog, semiconductors, solid-state-devices

I am trying to understand the MOS-Capacitor band edge shapes. When negative voltage is applied for gate, why does the band edge across the insulator shift upward (and linear decreasing band edge)?  Similarly, when positive voltage is applied to gate, why does the band edge across the insulator shift downward (and linearly decreasing band edge)?

When gate voltage is positive, why does the energy level of metal shift down in band diagram? And vice versa?

I looked up previous questions relevant to this topic and couldn't find this question. Please direct me to that, if you think someone has already answered this question.

Comment: In the diagrams up means the electrons gain energy. Voltage has the opposite direction (down means increasing voltage).

Answer (score 1):

The y-axis of a band diagram represent the energy of an electron. If you plot the energy of a positive elementary charge, it will be the mirror image of this about x-axis. So increasing voltage, which corresponds to potential energy of a positive charge, will reduce the energy of electron. That is why the energy level is shifted down on applying a positive voltage and vice versa.

See the diagrams below. First one shows positive gate voltage and second one shows negative gate voltage applied with respect to the substrate (Semiconductor). Some portion of the applied voltage will be dropped across semiconductor and remaining across the oxide. Because of this, the voltage at the left side and right of the oxide will be different. The more positive side will be lower than the other. That is why there is an upward slope for positive gate voltage and vice versa.

Since there are no charge inside the oxide (ideal MOS cap assumed), the electric field has to be uniform inside (read [Poisson's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation)) and hence potential vary linearly. And conduction band follows the potential variation. That's why the band edges are drawn linearly.

[image]